# Receiving error when calling Kubernetes API from the Pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have .NET Standard (4.7.2) simple application that is containerized. It has a method to list all namespaces in a cluster. I used [csharp kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp) to interact with the API. According to [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) the default credential of API server are created in a pod and used to communicate with API server, but while calling kubernetes API from the pod, getting following error:

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

My deployment yaml is very minimal:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cmd-dotnetstdk8stest
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: windows
  containers:
  - name: cmd-dotnetstdk8stest
    image: eddyuk/dotnetstdk8stest:1.0.8-cmd
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80`

Comment: Seems you have not the right to access this api. Consider adding details?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have RBAC activatet inside your Cluster. You need to assign a ServiceAccount to your pod which containing a Role, that allows this ServerAccount to get a list of all Namespaces. When no ServiceAccount is specified in the Pod-Template, the namespaces default ServiceAccount will be assigned to the pods running in this namespace.

First, you should create the Role

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: <YOUR NAMESPACE>
  name: namespace-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["namespaces"] # Resource is namespaces
  verbs: ["get", "list"] # Allowing this roll to get and list namespaces
```

Create a new ServiceAccount inside your Namespace

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: application-sa
  namespace: <YOUR-NAMESPACE>
```

Assign your Role created Role to the Service-Account:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: allow-namespace-listing
  namespace: <YOUR-NAMESPACE>
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: application-sa # Your newly created Service-Account
  namespace: <YOUR-NAMESPACE>
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: namespace-reader # Your newly created Role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Assign the new Role to your Pod by adding a ServiceAccount to your Pod Spec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: podname
  namespace: <YOUR-NAMESPACE>
spec:
  serviceAccountName: application-sa
```

You can read [more about RBAC in the official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/). Maybe you want to [use kubectl-Commands instead of YAML](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#command-line-utilities) definitions.

Comment: Thanks! The example you provided still gave me an error but pointed me in a right direction. In the RoleBinding I changed subjects kind from user to ServiceAccount and replaced apiGroup with namespace and then it worked!